# Objective-C method return type with generics and Xcode autocomplete

Tags: objective-c, xcode, generics, methods, return-type

I have custom collection class with generic parameterisation. I create collection of cats, add cat. When I try to get cat back Xcode is showing error: "Property 'name' not found on object of type 'id'". This is nonsense, because `Cat` has property `name` and `MyCustomCollection` doesn't return `id` but `ObjectType`. How do I declare method so the autocompletion could understand which type is returning by the method?

```
MyCustomCollection *collection = [[MyCustomCollection<Cat *> alloc] init];
[collection addCustomObject:[[Cat alloc] init]];
NSString *string = [collection customObjectAtIndex:0].name; // Property 'name' not found on object of type 'id'
```

MyCustomCollection.h file

```
@interface MyCustomCollection<ObjectType> : NSObject
-(ObjectType)customObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
-(void)addCustomObject:(ObjectType)object;
@end
```

Cat.h file

```
@interface Cat : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with the method declaration. It is the declaration of the `collection` variable. You have to tell the compiler what type of objects are in the collection:

```
MyCustomCollection<Cat *> *collection = [[MyCustomCollection<Cat *> alloc] init];
```

Otherwise it won't know what sort of objects the `collection` variable references and assumes that they are of type `id` (hence the error).

You theoretically can also cast the result of `customObjectAtIndex`, but that seems to defeat the purpose of using generics.